# Python for loop breaks text based game

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, text-based

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import time
import os

class vars:
    running = 1

def win ():
    print("You escaped!")
    vars.running = 0
    time.sleep(4)
    return 0

def main ():
    char_loc = 11 #The characters current co-ordinates in XY format
    pos_char_loc = 11
    ex_y = random.randint(1, 5)
    ex_x = random.randint(1, 5) * 10
    ex_loc = ex_x + ex_y

    while vars.running == 1:
        os.system('CLS')
        x0 = ["#"] * 5
        x1 = ["#"] * 5
        x2 = ["#"] * 5
        x3 = ["#"] * 5
        x4 = ["#"] * 5
        if (char_loc >= 11  and char_loc <= 55):
            if (char_loc >= 11 and char_loc <= 15):
                i = 0; k = 11
                for x in range(0, 4):          
                    if char_loc == k:
                        x0.insert(i, '@')
                    else:
                        i += 1
                        k += 1 
            if (char_loc >= 21 and char_loc <= 25):
                i =0; k = 21
                for loop1 in range(0, 4):
                    if char_loc == k:
                        x1.insert(i, '@')
                    else:
                        i += 1
                        k += 1
            if (char_loc >= 31 and char_loc <= 35):
                i =0; k = 31
                for loop2 in range(0, 4):
                    if char_loc == k:
                        x2.insert(i, '@')
                    else:
                        i += 1
                        k += 1                                
            if (char_loc >= 41 and char_loc <= 45):
                i =0; k = 41
                for loop3 in range(0, 4):
                    if char_loc == k:
                        x3.insert(i, '@')
                    else:
                        i += 1
                        k += 1
            if (char_loc >= 51 and char_loc <= 55):
                i =0; k = 51
                for loop5 in range(0, 4):
                    if char_loc == k:
                        x4.insert(i, '@')
                    else:
                        i += 1
                        k += 1
            else:
                print("fail")

        print( x0[4],x1[4],x2[4],x3[4],x4[4])
        print( x0[3],x1[3],x2[3],x3[3],x4[3])
        print( x0[2],x1[2],x2[2],x3[2],x4[2])
        print( x0[1],x1[1],x2[1],x3[1],x4[1])
        print( x0[0],x1[0],x2[0],x3[0],x4[0])
        print(char_loc, ex_loc)
        if char_loc == ex_loc:
            win()         
        move = input()
        if move == "w" and (char_loc != 15 and char_loc != 25 and char_loc != 35 and char_loc != 45 and char_loc !=55):
            char_loc += 1
            print("up")
        elif move == "s" and (char_loc != 11 and char_loc != 21 and char_loc != 31 and char_loc != 41 and char_loc != 51):
            char_loc -= 1
            print("down")
        elif move == "a" and (char_loc != 11 and char_loc != 12 and char_loc != 13 and char_loc != 14 and char_loc != 15):
            char_loc -= 10
            print("left")
        elif move == "d" and (char_loc != 51 and char_loc != 52 and char_loc != 53 and char_loc != 54 and char_loc != 55):
            char_loc += 10
            print("right")
        else: print("You can't move there!")

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I'm trying to make a simple text based game where you move the '@' around a grid of '#'s
and try to find the exit. I've changed the code to make it easier for me to make the grid bigger or smaller without adding or deleting huge chunks of code and it keeps on giving me this output:

```
fail
# # # # #
@ # # # #
@ # # # #
@ # # # #
@ # # # #
11 52
```

and I can't figure out what's wrong with it! Only one '@' is supposed to appear :(
I am only a newbie at python so if you have any tips for improving this please, don't hesitate, and post them!
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your code has got too much whitespace overall; can you remove the excessive blank lines and reduce indentation? 4 spaces per level is much more readable. There appear to be some indentation errors in in the code as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've done that, but it still fails.

Comment: I didn't say that that would fix your problem. :-P I only wanted to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, Ok. Thanks i'll keep that in mind in future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "fail" occurs because it will occur every time the char_loc is not between 51 and 55.

```
if (char_loc >= 11 and char_loc <= 15):
if (char_loc >= 21 and char_loc <= 25):
if (char_loc >= 31 and char_loc <= 35):
if (char_loc >= 41 and char_loc <= 45):
if (char_loc >= 51 and char_loc <= 55):
else:
```

What I think you'd want to do here is use elif, which will only fire if the previous checks don't trigger.

```
if (char_loc >= 11 and char_loc <= 15):
elif (char_loc >= 21 and char_loc <= 25):
elif (char_loc >= 31 and char_loc <= 35):
elif (char_loc >= 41 and char_loc <= 45):
elif (char_loc >= 51 and char_loc <= 55):
else:
```

In regards to the multiple @ symbols, I think this may play a part.  Currently you have:

```
if char_loc == k:
    x0.insert(i, '@')
else:
    i += 1
    k += 1
```

What I think you're looking to do is:

```
if char_loc == k:
    x0.insert(i, '@')

i += 1
k += 1
```

Since you want k to change every time that loop iterates.

One last thing that I would suggest is since you have:

```
i =0; k = 21
i =0; k = 31
i =0; k = 41
i =0; k = 51
```

You will probably want to add

```
i =0; k = 11
```

To the first one.

Hope that helps.